# Use MQTT or remote MySQL to get data on a server?

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I currently set up several Raspberry Pis in different locations that collect data (temperature, humidity)  every 5 seconds. To visualize that data I'm wondering if it's better to send that data via MQTT to a VPS and save it to a local MySQL database or just use a remote MySQL connection and insert the data directly into the MySQL database.
Currently, I can't really see any advantages of MQTT. Do any of u have other opinions?

Thanks and greetings,
Jonas.

Comment: "...or just use a remote MySQL connection and insert the data directly into the MySQL database" -- using a remote connection over an unstrusted network is unsafe and is also very unstable and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Any answer to this is going to be somewhat opinion based but I believe that the following are some areas where MQTT may provide you with benefits:

- Message delivery (especially over poor quality links) - with MQTT (and QOS>0) once the message has been accepted delivery is guaranteed (within limits!); the client/broker will handle network issues etc. Note that some MQTT clients do not support offline buffering (for example the [Paho .Net client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/downloads.php)) but you can resolve this by running a broker on each Pi setup as a bridge. If you use MySQL then you will need to deal with connectivity issues yourself (and handle data persistence during network outages if that is important to you).
- Bandwidth - MQTT messages are likely to be smaller (this depends upon how you pack your messages but the protocol adds very little overhead).
- Security - the MySQL [security guidelines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/security-guidelines.html) state that the MySQL "port should not be accessible from untrusted hosts". Any product can have security issues but MySQL is a much larger and more complex system than an MQTT broker so has a larger attack surface.
- Loose Coupling - Connecting directly to the database from your remote nodes locks you into that database & schema. Using MQTT allows you to rearchitect your backend (including moving to, say, PostgreSQL) without pushing out any changes to the client (important when you have a lot of remote devices or cannot remotely update them).
- Pub/Sub model - The Publish/Subscribe model used by MQTT offers a number of advantages such as subscribing to live data from your test system.
- Bi-Directional - If you need to, for example, control a relay on your remote device then it's easy to send a message to it from the server (this can also be used to do things like request logs for diagnostics).

Comment: Great answer, many thanks! I thought about using MySQL bi-directional too (with constant checking on changes in a table), but MQTT might be the better option in the end. I'm currently figuring out if I want to use AWS IoT Core or do the MQTT to MySQL handling by myself.